# Designing a schema for players and tournaments

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design

I am beginner in SQL, I have a simple MySQL database which contains two tables:

1. Players (id, name)
2. Tournaments (id, name, participants)

I want to save information about participants of every tournament. The first idea that I have is that `participants` should contain a large number of `id` fields from the `players` table but that doesn't seem good.

How should I design this in the correct way?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Make another table called Participants with two fields. Player_ID and Tournament_ID. This table can hold as many lines as it needs to to correlate who played when, and you can cross reference it as needed.

Answer (score 3):

Remove "participants" from the second table and add a third table: TournamentPlayers (playerid, tournamentid).

You should avoid storing multiple values in one field. That would break the first normal form of database design (1NF), which states that only atomic values can be stored in one field. Relational database systems are not well-suited to cope with non-normalized data, and you *will* have a hard time writing queries for non-1NF tables.